# Why do spaces appear in my string?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this function below which returns all IDs of checked boxes on my page seperated by a comma. It works great but the problem is, it seems to put a lot of white space after each checkbox ID. I can't seem to figure out why?

```
/*Returns selected checkbox ID in string seperated by comma */
function get_selected_chkbox(){

    var checked_string = '';

     $('#report_table').find("input[type='checkbox']").each(function(){

        if(this.checked){

            checked_string = checked_string + this.id + ',';

        }

    });

            alert(checked_string);//test1         ,test2            ,   

    return checked_string;
}
```

Thanks all for any help

Comment: Can you confirm using `console.log()` or some other way of outputting the string that this is nothing specific to the `alert()`?

Comment: You have a sample of the html you could paste?

Comment: @Pekka - Yes, I use Firebug and I use that string as GET variable in a request and in the URL there are loads of `+` indicating a space. I also have to do work at the backend to remove the spaces.

Comment: @Chuck good question. Having a look at my generated HTML file, there are lots of spaces in my ID fields! Investigating now...

Comment: Strange. The IDs of the checkboxes are in order? Can you show a HTML sample?

Comment: Ah, overlooked your last comment. That's probably it - if there are spaces in the ID, they will be in the `id` property as well.

Comment: @Pekka - you are right, I didn't think to look at the source, spent most of the time looking at the function!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can rewrite your function like this

```
var selected = new Array();
$('#report_table input:checkbox:checked').each(function(){
    selected.push($(this).attr("id"));
});

return selected.join(',');
```

***Edit***

Better to get rid of spaces in id rather than trimming the ids in javascript.

Comment: @Rahul - I still need to find where the spaces are coming from but I'll be using your function, much cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

Use this to get rid of the white spaces :)

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/

$.trim(checked_string);

Answer (score 1):

I would guess that the spaces are in the html.

Try (with a nod to @rahul's answer):

```
return $.makeArray($('#report_table input:checkbox:checked').map(function(){
  return $.trim($(this).attr('id'));
})).join(',');
```

(And, it appears, a nod to @Tim's answer!)

Comment: I'm pretty sure that with the map function on a wrapped set that you can skip the parameters to the callback and simply use 'this' in place of el.

Comment: You're quite right! I also needed to makeArray it as it's not a real array.

Answer (score 1):

please add your html code for the checkbox. It may possible you write

```
<input type="checkbox" id="test1        "/>
```

Answer (score 0):

or `this.id.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '')` would work